# Can't seem to find app icon in Android Emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

Like I asked in the title, I'm creating the ToDo_List app as per instructions given in Professional Android Application Development 2 and after clearing a few bugs I managed to compile and run the Emulator.

After waiting a few minutes for the emulator to load I go to the menu and I can't seem to locate my app. Any ideas?

Thanks

Edit:
After a little checking this is the error I get

[2010-09-11 13:11:05 - ToDo_List] ERROR: Application requires API version 7. Device API version is 6 (Android 2.0.1).

Answer (score 1):

Your app was never installed on the emulator because the app requires API version 7 and the emulator runs version 6. Create an emulator that runs version 7 or change the minimum api requirement in your manifest.

Answer (score 0):

Run `adb install yourapkname.apk` in the terminal of android studio. It worked for me.